# remove project from compiling in build.xml when using ccnet

Tags: xml, cruisecontrol.net

I get this error becouse i am using ccnet and i don't have installed VS in this computer:

```
NCrawler.DbServices.Db.dbproj(63,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\TeamData\Microsoft.Data.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

how can in build.xml remove Crawler.DbServices.Db.dbproj project from compiling? Is this possible.

This is my build.xml for curisecontrol

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <Solution>NCrawler.sln</Solution>       
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="!Exists('$(Configuration)')">
        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>    
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Compile" />

    <Target Name="Clean">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(Solution)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" Targets="Clean" />  
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Compile">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(Solution)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" />   
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your solution to specify which projects are built for each configuration  (e.g., Release/Debug, etc.)

In Visual Studio, open your solution file (NCrawler.sln) and go to the **Build/Configuration Manager...** menu option.  Then uncheck the projects you do not want built (Crawler.DbServices.Db.dbproj) for each configuration/platform combination.  Then save your solution.